# Absolute Value inequality Equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

For a,b ∈ R, check if $|a−b|\leq5$ is an equivalence relation.

- Reflexive: a ~ a because $|a-a|=0\leq5$
- Symmetric: Let $b~a$, $|b-a|≤5  \Rightarrow |a-b|≤5$, which means that a~b
- Transitive: a~b and $b~c  \Rightarrow
  |a-b|≤5  \Rightarrow -5≤ a-b ≤5$ (1)
  $|b-c|≤5  \Rightarrow -5≤ b-c ≤5$ (2)

If I add (1),(2) i'll have: $-10≤ a-c ≤10  \Rightarrow |a-c|≤10$
Are the steps correct? Is the relation transitive or no?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two steps are correct.

And, no, it is *not* transitive. In order to prove it, just provide an example. For instance: $0\sim4$ and $4\sim8$, but $0\not\sim8$.